# LwIP IPv6 config

Tags: ipv6

I am trying to compile lwIP stack for STM32F4 for use with IPv6. But there are many errors. I suppose core/ipv4 and include/ipv4 directories are not necessary (the header files with the same names exist in ipv6 folder). But not all definitions exist in ipv6 version of headers. What to do - get the ipv4 headers or?

Comment: At the moment the newest version of lwip can only use IPv4 AND OPTIONALLY IPv6. You need the headers for IPv4!

Comment: I know this and tried to compile with IPv6 (without IPv4). And the compilation (errors = 0) is nearly impossible. I suspect that last attempt/test to compile IPv6 by developers has been few versions ago. Later there are changes in header files which make incompatible IPv6 part.

Comment: But it is not possible to compile without IPv4 in recent versions, this is by design.

Comment: You can compile either with IPv4 only, or with IPv4 and IPv6.

Comment: Are you sure and have you tried to do this?

Comment: "Support for IPv6 is currently being added to LwIP. Up to version 1.4.x LwIP can use either IPv4 or IPv6, but not both. Code for dual Stack operation is in the current development version (which can be downloaded from git). It will probably be released as version 1.5.0..."

Comment: Yes i am sure, i am using the latest development version, directly from the git repository. (1.4.1 is almost 2 years old).

Comment: OK. I was talking about 1.4.1 which is the official stable version.

Comment: Okay, as far as I know IPv6 support is extremely limited in 1.4.1, you may consider using the development version.